# Thymeleaf OGNL To display HttpSession variables

Tags: iteration, enumeration, thymeleaf, ognl

It is pretty easy to access individual session variables by name in *OGNL* / *Thymeleaf* for display.  The session variables however is a `getAttributeNames()` : Enumeration while the `getValueNames()` is deprecated (implying that I do not want to use the latter option).

So how do one iterate, using *Thymeleaf*, over the attribute Names and display their values if it as an Enumeration?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The implicit Thymeleaf **session** object is an instance of VariablesMap (a org.thymeleaf.context.**WebSessionVariablesMap** according to the docs) and can therefore be iterated over with the standard **th:each** attribute. The iteration variable is an instance of `Map.Entry<K,V>`. So for example:

```
<ol>
    <li th:each="attributeEntry : ${session}">
        <span th:text="${attributeEntry.key + ': ' + attributeEntry.value}"></span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks!  Perfect.  I got stuck trying the #httpSession.

Comment: Great, glad it sorted it :-)

Comment: @user1210708 - please consider accepting this answer (or any others that are submitted that may improve on it) so others in the community facing the same issue can see there is a relevant solution - many thanks.